# How to remove a specific tuple from a array of tuples in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

```
arrayOfTuples = [(4, 4, "id1"), (3, 6, "id2"), (3, 6, "id3")]
```

How to remove the item with the `id2` string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RangeReplaceableCollection` method `removeAll(where:)` and pass a predicate:

```
var arrayOfTuples = [(4, 4, "id1"), (3, 6, "id2"), (3, 6, "id3")]
arrayOfTuples.removeAll(where: {$2 == "id2"})
print(arrayOfTuples)  // [(4, 4, "id1"), (3, 6, "id3")]
```

If you would like to remove only the first occurrence where the third element of your tuple is equal to "id2" you can use `Collection`'s method `firstIndex(where:)`:

```
if let index = arrayOfTuples.firstIndex(where: {$2 == "id2"}) {
    arrayOfTuples.remove(at: index)
}
```